# Crawling different sites with nutch 1.8

Tags: nutch

i am using nutch 1.8 to crawling information from sites who has different patterns from same field. I was writing plugins for each of that sites the , but when i start nutch, just first plugin is matching with all sites, others as they are not exists.

If the first plugin is not matched with site, skip to next one and check them, etc until you find the right plugin for site?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you are getting this. Are you writing a HTMLParseFilter? What you could do is to exit the parse method if the current document's URL does not match a given pattern or alternatively pass some metadata from the seeds which you could use to determine which HTMLParseFilter implementation to use.

BTW you'd get a more relevant audience by posting on the Nutch user list (see http://nutch.apache.org/mailing_lists.html)